# How do I determine what API levels developers have in their Android SDK?

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt

The ADT New Samples Project dialog is dynamic and returns only the Target SDK's available. Can the Build.VERSION_CODES (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) work beyond device api level?  Or do I have to traverse the file system to programmatically determine where the user has installed the Android SDK at?  I know the SDK location is accessible from the Eclipse workbench preferences page, but is there an API call that I can hook into instead of traversing the file system?

Comment: `Beyond the device api level`? I didn't get your question buddy. Can you explain more?

Comment: The question needs more clarification. Are you develop something for the ADT and eclipse or for a device? And by "the user" you mean one developer which uses the eclipse and or the ADT or a device end user?